# Use GPU installation of tensorflow/cuda in spyder under ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow, spyder

I am running ubuntu 14.04 with an anaconda2 installation and would like to use tensorflow in combination with CUDA. So far the steps I performed are:

1. Installed CUDA 7.5 and cudnn
2. Installed tensorflow (GPU version) through a DEB package. Note that I don't want to use the conda package of tensorflow since that one is not the GPU version.
3. Added Anaconda, CUDA and cudnn to path.
4. Created a conda environment for tensorflow (conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7)

Now if I start python or IDLE from the terminal, I can import tensorflow and it will find all the CUDA dependencies, great!

...however, if I start ipython or spyder from the same terminal, running "import tensorflow as tf" gives me a cold-hearted "ImportError: No module named tensorflow".

My question: How can I get ipython and spyder to find the tensorflow library just like in an IDLE and a python instance?

Comment: Are you sure that the they use the same python environment?

Comment: Spyder is pointing to ~/anaconda2/bin/python as its python executable. My tensorflow is installed in ~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/bin. Seems like it's the same environment? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Update. Ok, I think I got it. So apparently within the tensorflow environment I was able to install ipython again and now it does recognize tensorflow. Same trick did not solve it for spyder though.

Comment: Do you have spyder and ipython installed in your tensorflow environment? What is the output of `source activate tensorflow && conda list`?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue you have 3 options here:

1 just start spyder from terminal

2  move PATH variable definition from .bash_profile to session init scripts

3 Duplicate your PATH in spyder's run configuration