# Installing Tensorflow in Conda enviroment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter-lab

I have a problem with installing Tensorflow(Tf). Firstly, I installed Tensorflow to conda enviroment from Terminal. And i imported Tensorflow on Terminal

```
python
import tensorflow as tf
```

It worked. Then I opened jupyter Lab, i setted kernel to my enviroment. And I tried to import Tf, it failed.

I installed Tf as following;

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0
```

and I used this command to see what i installed

```
conda list
```

output is like this:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

tensorboard               1.10.0           py35hf484d3e_0    defaults 
tensorflow                1.10.0          gpu_py35h566a776_0    defaults 
tensorflow-base           1.10.0          gpu_py35h6ecc378_0    defaults 
tensorflow-gpu            1.10.0               hf154084_0    defaults
```

***Configuration:***

- Anaconda3
- Python: 3.5
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

***Edit:***

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fec9a2f62822> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 slim = tf.contrib.slim
      3 import numpy as np
      4 from IPython.display import clear_output
      5 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Can you tell us about the error output on the Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Just tried with the same environment I had no problemswithout tensorflow-gpu. What is your GPU hardware specification? Do you have Cuda/Cudnn installed ?

Comment: GeForce GTX 1070. Cuda 9.0, Cudnn 7. And it worked from Terminal, If it is about these, It shouldn't worked on Terminal screen. I can not figure it out.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236677/use-gpu-installation-of-tensorflow-cuda-in-spyder-under-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1 it seems it is a different PATH between the IPython notebook and the Python in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was about PATH. It was used IPython from local. Installed Ipython into conda enviroment and it was fixed.